# Is there any way to use field values for coldefs from API Call in Ag-Grid( Angular)?

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I have to make an API call from where I will get field values for coldefs in the form of key-value pair. I have to use 'key' as fields and 'value' as headerName. Is there any way to do this ?

```
let url2 = "xyz";
this.http.get(url2).subscribe(res => 
 { this.rowData2 = res; }
 );
/* From above code I am fetching data and saving in variable rowData2*/
```

Suppose the key,value pair obtained from rowData2 variable is:

```
 {
 key_Name1: "Value_Name1",
 key_Name2: "Value_Name2",
 key_Name3: "Value_Name3",
 } 

this.columnDefs = [ 
/*How can I apply loop here in order to go through all key-value pairs 
fetched from url and stored in rowData2 variable.*/
  { headerName:'Value_Name', field: 'Key_Name', filter: true, sortable: true, 
 resizable: true }
];
```

Comment: Please put code examples of what you have tried and did not succeed.

Comment: let url2 = "http://xyz";
    this.http.get(url2).subscribe(res => { this.rowData2 = res; });
/* From above code I am fetching data*/

Comment: this.columnDefs = [
/*How can I apply loop here in order to go through all key-value pairs fetched from url and stored in rowdata2 variable.*/
      { headerName:'Value_Name', field: 'Key_Name', filter: true, sortable: true, resizable: true }
    ];

Comment: Edit your question and use code formatting please instead of using comments.

Comment: I hope it's clear now